# framework not found UserMessagingPlatform after updating admob

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob, cocoapods

After updating pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' to '7.64.0', I can't compile my project.

```
framework not found UserMessagingPlatform
```

As you can read here https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/ios/quick-start

The UMP SDK is included as a dependency of the Google Mobile Ads SDK Pod starting with Google Mobile Ads SDK 7.64.0. So I did pod install with cocoapods 1.10.0 and I can see this:

```
Installing Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (7.64.0)
Installing GoogleAppMeasurement (6.1.6)
Installing GoogleDataTransport (3.2.0)
Installing GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (1.2.2)
Installing GoogleUserMessagingPlatform (1.4.0)
Installing GoogleUtilities (6.3.2)
```

Then, it's installed, but, why is giving me that error?

I cleaned deriveddata and cocoapods cache folders

So, what is wrong?

Comment: Does it show up in the Podfile.lock?

Comment: @PaulBeusterien yes, it is there...

Comment: What's the CocoaPods version? xcframework support has had several bug fixes in recent releases and some bugs are still outstanding

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem.
Using cocoa pods I uninstalled the google ads sdk completely then I reinstalled it and it all compiled fine.
Go figure.